# When some conditions triggers, have to do automatic file transfer over bluetooth using Android Bluetooth API?

Tags: android, file, bluetooth

In my application i want send a file or text over Bluetooth to another Bluetooth device(receiver device may be android,Nokia,LG,etc..). I want to send a file whenever the sever returns the data. For example am checking weather if the climate level falls below any particular given value. It automatically, need to send data over Bluetooth to the receiver device. It wont allow the user to send.
How can I implement it using android Bluetooth API?

And also I need to transfer any file via Bluetooth by converting it to byte array. I have gone through Bluetooth chat example. In that they have given the buffer size of 1024. If the file size more than 1024 byte means how should I transfer. Whether I have to sent each 1024 byte every time and have to merge it at the receiver side or else any other better way is available?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand you're asking three questions.

1. *How to send a file whenever a server returns data*: You basically open a connection to the server (e.g. `http`, but might also be any other TCP or UDP-based protocol). Then you listen for incoming data; once you receive data, you trigger whatever action you want. These are some relevant calls for a starting point when your server is not using `http` (untested, consult the docs for details and alternatives):

   ```
   Socket s = new Socket('your.server.com', 47000);
   s.connect();
   SocketChannel c = s.getChannel();
   ByteBuffer buffer = new ByteBuffer(1);
   c.read(buffer); // blocks until bytes are available
   ```
2. *How to initiate a Bluetooth connection automatically*: Obtain the target device's `BluetoothDevice` object, then connect to it - as in the BluetoothChat demo.
3. *How to send a file / more than 1024 bytes via Bluetooth*: Yes you have to split your data into blocks on the sending side and reassemble them on the receiving side (mind to send the filesize before the actual data, so the receiver knows when the file is complete). You can also use reasonably larger byte buffers. I'd recommand using a maximum block size of 64 Kb: This allows you to resend blocks without too much (time) cost and doesn't consume too much memory.

As a starter regarding 3., something like this could the core of the sending side (untested and without error handling, just to give the idea):

```
// Send the file size
OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
ByteBuffer header = ByteBuffer.allocate(8);
header.putLong(file.length();
out.write(header.array());

// Send the file in chunks
byte buffer[1024];
InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
int length = in.read(buffer);
while (length > 0) {
    out.write(buffer, 0, length);
    if (length < 1024) break;
    length = in.read(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
};
```

... and the receiving side:

```
// Receive and unmarshal the file size
InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
ByteBuffer header = ByteBuffer.allocate(8);
byte buffer[1024];
in.read(buffer, 0, 8);
header.put(buffer);
long filesize = header.getLong();
long receivedBytes = 0;

// Receive the file
OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
int length = in.read(buffer);
while ((receivedBytes < filesize) && (length > 0)){
    out.write(buffer, 0, length);
    receivedBytes += length;
    length = in.read(buffer);
}
if (receivedBytes != filesize) ... // Assure the transfer was successful
```

Comment: Hi domsom: Thanks for your valuable reply. I am having a problem with send simple image file over bluetooth using bluetooth chat sample. Actually, My requirement was an send any file over bluetooth. Now I am trying sending a image file, For this how can I set the buffer size, how to receive small chunk of data and combine it at the receiver side. Could u please share me your code.

Comment: I don't have code for that, but I just added some sample lines to give the idea...

Comment: You are saying that two different project. one is client then another one is server. Now I am modifying the bluetooth chat sample. In that sample they have converted the chat message into byte array. Here I have to convert the file to byte array and have to pass the parameter of byte array. Now My doubt is I want to implement two way communication like Bluetooth chat. Have to transfer file from both the end like Bluetooth chat works.

Comment: @MVignesh no worries, you can organize your code so that both sides can act as senders and receivers. If you're using the same Bluetooth connection for actual chat, you should mark the beginning of a file transfer with a special "chat message", so the receiving side knows it should run the file receiving code instead of the chat message code.

Comment: Could you please tell me where and how can I integrate it with android bluetooth chat example. Am new to that. And also lot of stuffs in that chat example to understand. Once again thanks for your effort domsom. If u tell where to change in android bluetooth chat, it might be helpful for more people, because I found lot of questions related to that.

Comment: @MVignesh The code snippets should go to `BluetoothChatService`'s private `ConnectedThread` class. The stream stuff is already there basically. Getting it into the example's code requires glue code in quite some places, so posting such code would be out of scope here.  I'd be happy if you publish your solution once it's done and then post a link here, though.